# Change windows default path or last used path for saving files? Is that possible?

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-registry

I'm trying to change the default saving path to my specfied path for example if the file is picture (.jpg .gif etc..) and using google chrome I save an image the path can be anything from default or last used
so I want it to be mine specfied for example I choose "C:\SaveHerePics"

I don't know how you can change it maybe Registry? Dll?

I would like to create vb.net program with textbox you choose the new location to be located every time for example "C:\SaveHerePics" and it should not have anything to do with this program even if you close the program the default location for pictures saved via any program or source saved to "C:\SaveHerePics"

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There is no such Windows default. It is up to the application programmer to remember such information. Over to you.

Comment: is there a way to manipulate it?

Comment: There is nothing to manipulate. There is no system wide setting. Each program does its own thing.